# REGEX in java for extracting consecutive duplicate characters in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, duplicates

**Question**: **Print** character(s) in a string that are repeated **consecutively** only **twice** (not more).

**Examples**: 
1)"aaabbaa" :  b  and  a  
2)"aabbaa"  :  a  and  b  and  a  
3)"abba"    :  b

**Code I tried**: 
String str = "aabbbbcccd";  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\w){2}");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);  
while(m.find())  
{  
System.out.println(m.group(1));  
}  

**Output**:
a
b
b
c
d   
Although, the desired output is 
a
d

**Postscript**
As I have recently started with regex, it would highly appreciated if the answerer can explain
the regex used briefly (especially quantifiers and groups).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single plain regex solution to this problem because you need a lookbehind with a backreference inside, which is not supported by Java regex engine.

What you can do is either get all `(\w)\1+` matches and then check their length using common string methods:

```java
String s = "aaabbaa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group().length() == 2) System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

(see the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/sTYQJZ)) or you can match 3 or more repetitions or just 2 repetitions and only grab the match if the Group 2 matched:

```java
String s = "aaabbaa";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1{2,}|(\\w)\\2");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/VAAiJS). *Regex details*:

- `(\w)\1{2,}` - a word char and two or more occurrences of the same char right after
- `|` - or
- `(\w)\2` - a word char and the same char right after.

Comment: Of course. I had some doubts:                                                                                                                                     
 1) In the first case, instead of using  <<(\\w)\\1+>> can I use <<"(\\w){1,}">> or            <<"(\\w){2}">>                                           
 2) Does <<\\1>> tells the  compiler that it is for group 1.                                                 
 3) Can I use <<{1,}>> instead of <<+>>

Comment: @believer `{1,}` is the same as `+`, it repeats the pattern it modifies one or more times. `\w+` matches one or more letters/digits/`_`, and thus matches `ab123_any___`, `123`, `_`, etc. The `\1` in `(\w)\1` is a backreference to the Group 1 value, and only matches what has been captured. Use whatever you need, it only depends on your real requirements, but one thing is certain: you cannot just change `\1` with `+`.